# How to detect all devices in a LAN?

Tags: broadcast, lan

I want to detect all devices in a LAN which have IP: 10.x.x.x Mask: 255.0.0.0.
I first wrote a synchronous ping program to ping IPs one by one, but it's tooooo slow.
Therefore I improved it by using asynchronous ping, then it's much faster.
Now I can use it to detect 10.x.0~255.0~255 in an acceptable time.
But it still use tooooooooooooo long time to detect all the IPs 10.0~255.0~255.0~255.

Is there any method/protocol that can just broadcast one message and let all devices in a LAN to respond, so I can detect all the devices?
(either Ethernet broadcast or UDP/IP broadcast or any other broadcast.)
(I've researched ARP & ICMP but haven't find suitable methods.)

Or any other method even don't need broadcast? 
I just need to detect all the devices, any method is OK.

Comment: There is no magic here, and you certainly cannot detect "all the devices" in any case.  Not everything responds to pings, and not everything will respond to any traffic you throw at it.  You can send an ICMP ping to the broadcast addresses, but most hosts these days don't respond to it. (Some do, however.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend "Angry IP Scanner" http://angryip.org/

It is fast, detects all devices in a given ip/netmask.

Angry IP scanner is a very fast IP address and port scanner.

From site:

> It can scan IP addresses in any range as well as any their ports. It
>   is cross-platform and lightweight. Not requiring any installations, it
>   can be freely copied and used anywhere.
>
> Angry IP scanner simply pings each IP address to check if it’s alive,
>   then optionally it is resolving its hostname, determines the MAC
>   address, scans ports, etc. The amount of gathered data about each host
>   can be extended with plugins.
>
> It also has additional features, like NetBIOS information (computer
>   name, workgroup name, and currently logged in Windows user), favorite
>   IP address ranges, web server detection, customizable openers, etc.

Comment: Thanks! But this ping program is even a little slower than my own program, not suitable fot detect all the IPs range from 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's what you are looking for but you can go in command prompt and run the command:

```
arp -a
```

Comment: Thanks! But this command line can not list all the devices for many reasons, especially when my detector PC just plug in the LAN. I need a more actively method.

Comment: Then you might need a software to do so. I find SoftPerfect really easy to use. http://www.softperfect.com/products/networkscanner/

Comment: Thanks! But SoftPerfect still too slow to detect all the IPs range from 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255.

Answer (score 0):

I think listening to arp broadcast packets would be a solution. Ofcourse it just work in a LAN. (I think your lan is very large.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!
From what I can remember, the LAN range is a default setting of my previous company's system, and they are deployed at many different places, one place one standalone system, so I can't change, but need to go there and debug from time to time.
But it's too long ago, I can't test now ~